# Distributing project into multiple WAR files

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, netbeans, war

I currently have a Java EE Netbeans project with multiple servlets. Some of these servlets are dependent on the same classes and libraries, and some are not.

At the moment a single WAR file is built, containing all classes and servlets.
What I'm trying to do tell the IDE to build one WAR for each servlet, where the WAR contains the dependencies along with the servlet itself.

I've tried looking through the build.xml for what tags to override, but I don't find anything that suits my needs.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I think that you should build a EAR...

Comment: @inigoD the WARs will not necessarily be deployed on the same server.

Comment: I believe the only way is to split the servlets into a separate projects, each project will then be a WAR on its own. But I would be glad if someone proves me wrong and shows a better way.